# problem in showing the output of the network after normalization

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a network and it has 2 outputs. I am working in keras and I use MNIST for the database. At first I normalized the values of training and testing samples

```
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_validation = x_validation.astype('float32') / 255.
```

I do not use activation for one of the outputs. when I want to show this output its value is between 0 and 2.91 and when I show the output its produce this image:
[image]

but I expect the number to be white because I think it considers the range of value between 0-255 while I want it to consider 0-1 range. what is the problem? but for my next output although the values are between 0 an 1 it shows a black and white image
[image]
could you please tell me what is the problem and why has it happened?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking... If you don't use any activation the output values can be greater than 1